# Java: app crashes during connecting GSM USB modem

Tags: java, usb, gsm

I am working on an open-source application called FrontlineSMS which can be interfaced with GSM modems to send and receive SMS. The windows installer that is available through their website works fine. Since i wanted to modify it, I got the source code and built the jar and tried to launch it. When I plug in the GSM modem and launch the application, it sometimes detects the GSM device and i am even able to send and receive SMS. Or else
1.) I get the following error-

```
Launching FrontlineSMS for Windows... Stable Library
========================================= Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7 Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7 Error 0x5 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(860): Access is de ied.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x5 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(860): Access is de ied.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x57 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2352): The parame er is incorrect.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.

Error 0x1 at /home/bob/foo/rxtx-devel/build/../src/termios.c(2497): Incorrect f nction.
```

2.) OR the application sometimes crashes by creating a log file which contains:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x10009ccb, pid=4452, tid=3464
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x9ccb]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03433000):  JavaThread "SmsModem :: COM18" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3464, stack(0x070a0000,0x070f0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x038cfa10

Registers:
EAX=0x038cfa08, EBX=0x00000003, ECX=0x7c802413, EDX=0x00000001
ESP=0x070ef800, EBP=0x070ef9e8, ESI=0x3360b898, EDI=0x03433000
EIP=0x10009ccb, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x070ef800)
0x070ef800:   3360b8a0 6d9fbc40 6da2ed98 ffffffff
0x070ef810:   070ef848 6d8f0a2c 6d8f0340 070ef95c
0x070ef820:   070ef864 00000dfb 03433000 038cfa08
0x070ef830:   00000007 00000001 00000001 0000000a
0x070ef840:   03433bf4 fffffffe 070ef8f4 6d8f0b7a
0x070ef850:   070ef95c 03433bf8 6da6f210 6da6f538
0x070ef860:   070ef868 03433bf4 27f18708 27f18708
0x070ef870:   22eb9810 03433bc4 00000001 070ef898 

Instructions: (pc=0x10009ccb)
0x10009cbb:   45 1c 7c 19 8b 85 44 fe ff ff 8b 95 4c fe ff ff
0x10009ccb:   89 50 08 8b 55 f4 89 d0 e9 f8 01 00 00 c7 85 50 


Stack: [0x070a0000,0x070f0000],  sp=0x070ef800,  free space=13e070ef334k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x9ccb]
C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0xa05e]
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort.readByte()I+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read()I+61
j  org.smslib.CSerialDriver.getResponse()Ljava/lang/String;+36
j  net.frontlinesms.smsdevice.SmsModem._doDetection()Z+172
j  net.frontlinesms.smsdevice.SmsModem.run()V+18
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf049c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17fcf1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf0667]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf06dd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11a2a0]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1ddb14]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17f96c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort.readByte()I+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read()I+61
j  org.smslib.CSerialDriver.getResponse()Ljava/lang/String;+36
j  net.frontlinesms.smsdevice.SmsModem._doDetection()Z+172
j  net.frontlinesms.smsdevice.SmsModem.run()V+18
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x03433000 JavaThread "SmsModem :: COM18" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3464, stack(0x070a0000,0x070f0000)]
  0x0344b800 JavaThread "D3D Screen Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4404, stack(0x03dd0000,0x03e20000)]
  0x002b7800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3236, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]
  0x03f6f400 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=1888, stack(0x038e0000,0x03930000)]
  0x03ec2400 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=4300, stack(0x03740000,0x03790000)]
  0x032d8c00 JavaThread "EmailServerHandler" [_thread_blocked, id=5708, stack(0x03830000,0x03880000)]
  0x032f7000 JavaThread "Incoming message processor" [_thread_blocked, id=4184, stack(0x03650000,0x036a0000)]
  0x03004c00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4828, stack(0x035a0000,0x035f0000)]
  0x0303f400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3768, stack(0x03500000,0x03550000)]
  0x02b1e800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4164, stack(0x02dd0000,0x02e20000)]
  0x02b18c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2936, stack(0x02d80000,0x02dd0000)]
  0x02b17400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5444, stack(0x02d30000,0x02d80000)]
  0x02b15c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4976, stack(0x02ce0000,0x02d30000)]
  0x02b0d800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5876, stack(0x02c90000,0x02ce0000)]
  0x02b0c400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5984, stack(0x02c40000,0x02c90000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02b0ac00 VMThread [stack: 0x02bf0000,0x02c40000] [id=4508]
  0x02b29800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e20000,0x02e70000] [id=6080]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 7808K, used 4003K [0x22990000, 0x23200000, 0x27ee0000)
  eden space 6976K,  45% used [0x22990000, 0x22ca8e90, 0x23060000)
  from space 832K, 100% used [0x23060000, 0x23130000, 0x23130000)
  to   space 832K,   0% used [0x23130000, 0x23130000, 0x23200000)
 tenured generation   total 17208K, used 15192K [0x27ee0000, 0x28fae000, 0x32990000)
   the space 17208K,  88% used [0x27ee0000, 0x28db6100, 0x28db6200, 0x28fae000)
 compacting perm gen  total 13824K, used 13655K [0x32990000, 0x33710000, 0x36990000)
   the space 13824K,  98% used [0x32990000, 0x336e5f98, 0x336e6000, 0x33710000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x36990000, 0x36ebae00, 0x36ebae00, 0x37390000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x37390000, 0x37a272d8, 0x37a27400, 0x37f90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f02000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da97000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x774e0000 - 0x7761d000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d284000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000  C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x16080000 - 0x160a5000  C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Iphlpapi.dll
0x63560000 - 0x63568000  C:\Program Files\National Instruments\Shared\mDNS Responder\nimdnsNSP.dll
0x63550000 - 0x63559000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\nimdnsResponder.dll
0x78130000 - 0x781cb000  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_x-ww_e6967989\MSVCR80.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10012000  C:\Documents and Settings\bjz677\Desktop\client run\rxtxSerial.dll
0x73d90000 - 0x73db7000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\crtdll.dll
0x4fdd0000 - 0x4ff76000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x038d0000 - 0x038d6000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d8thk.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x03930000 - 0x03977000  C:\Program Files\Iomega\DriveIcons\IMGHOOK.DLL
0x605d0000 - 0x605d9000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\mslbui.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL

VM Arguments:
java_command: net.frontlinesms.DesktopLauncher
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;
PATH=C:\Program Files\Intel\MKL\10.0.2.019\ia32\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\VTune\CGGlbCache;C:\Program Files\Intel\VTune\Analyzer\Bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\VTune\Shared\Bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;s:\datamart\bin;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\;C:\Program Files\IVI\bin;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32;C:\VXIPNP\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\Compiler\Fortran\10.1.021\\IA32\Lib;C:\Program Files\Intel\Compiler\Fortran\10.1.021\\EM64T\Lib;C:\VXIPNP\WinNT\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin
USERNAME=xxx
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2094960k(1063364k free), swap 4032536k(3038408k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.3-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_20-b02), built on Apr 12 2010 13:52:23 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Wed Jun 16 11:53:40 2010
elapsed time: 45 seconds
```

Does anyone know what causes it?

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) means access denied in windows, usually because you don't have permissions/rights to do what you're trying to do.

Your built jar likely needs to be signed to access the drivers.  This tells the java runtime that it's ok to access system drivers, the filesystem, etc.

Here's a tutorial:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

Answer (score 0):

We'd have to see the code, not just the error in termios.c. Most likely, there is an error in the native library that is called from Java. An Access Violation error typically occurs when you try to access a variable in memory that has been freed.

Comment: can you please let me know how i can access this code? is it a specific jar file?

Comment: `termios.c` and all the third party java code in the stack: `net.frontlinesms.smsdevice.SmsModem` through `gnu.io.RXTXPort`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, my solution was quite simple, i was using a USB-Serial Cable, the cable was a bad one, I just replaced the cable for a better one with a different driver, problem solve. The RxTxCom driver was having issues getting UART from the "PORT", thats why is crashing, here below the solution found some place else:

---

Thats the line number.  SetupComm failed.

termios.c(869):

```
     if( !SetupComm( port->hComm, 2048, 1024 ) )
     {
             YACK(); <===== 869
             return -1;
     }
```

SetupComm is a very old w32 API call so there is something unusual about 
the port.

YACK() is a helper macro that just spits out why the call failed.  "Yack, 
yack, yack!"  :)

My guess is that is not a real serial port but rather a driver trying to 
look like one [poorly].  A 'real' serial port has a UART and is typically 
recognized without additional drivers.  There isn't anything we can do to 
improve that function call from what I can tell.  You may look to see if 
there is a newer driver for the 'serial port' if what I said makes sense 
to you.

The only other thing I can suggest is that you don't want any other 
software using the port while you try to find it with rxtx.

---

Hope it helps you out.